# "Целоваться" и "целое"

Tags: этимология

В одном из своих концертов М. Задорнов говорил, что слова "целоваться" и "целое" - одного корня. Правда ли это? И, если да, как одно произошло от другого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Древняя форма *целовати* образована с помощью глагольного суффикса -ова-ти (как миловать) от праслав. прилагательного *целъ, целыи* «невредимый», «здоровый». Первонач. целовати значило «желать здоровья», собств. «желать быть здоровым, возвратиться (из похода, с охоты и т. п.) целым, невредимым». Впоследствии у глагола *целовать* развилось вторичное значение «прикосновением губ выражать хорошее отношение к кому-либо». (Цыганенко Г.П. Этимологический словарь русского языка)

Answer (score 1):

Да, слова родственны на старославянском уровне. "Целовать" - восходит к "цhль" с
морфами "приветсвовать", "здороваться"; "целый" в одном из исходжных значений тоже означает "здоровый".

*Только, бога ради, не слушайте вы Задорнова с его жалкими потугами на этимологию. Это случайность, обычно он сам не понимает, что несет*

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, "целовать" происходит от "человать", т.е. "прикладываться челом", возникло путем чередования ц-ч

Comment: поразительно, сколько в людях недоброты, мало того, что моему собственному ответу поставили минус, так ещё и мой голос за этот ответ аннулировали

Comment: Прочитала Ваш комментарий, и он меня немного удивил. Здесь дело не в доброте, просто на форуме категорически не приветствуется "народная этимология". Я также полагаю, что эта наука доступна только специалистам, так как здесь необходимо учитывать множество факторов и обладать глубокими знаниями многих смежных наук. Авторитетных этимологических словарей немного, и словарь Черных, о котором упоминает участник София, -  один из них.

Answer (score 0):

Целоваться - от "целый" (неповрежденный), о.-с. основа celovati от celъ - целый. Целовать - изначально благодарить, приветствовать, желать невредимости,  сравнить: здоровье - здороваться. Целовали священные предметы, также целовались в уста, приветствуя друг друга.

Интересно, что слово "поцелуй" еда ли было известно раньше 18 века.

Из словаря Черных П.Я.

Answer (score 0):

У германцев:
hāl "целый, зоровый" др.англ, heil пожелание "здоровья, удачи, счастья" др.в.нем.

Отсюда известные нам слова современного английского языка:
Hello, holy, health (привет, святой, здоровье).
Отсюда же имя Олег (из скандинавского helg).

У славян:
целовать (изначально "приветствовать"), целый, целительство.

Kails — это приветствие у пруссов (напоминает немецкое, но пруссы это балтское племя, близкое к литовцам, а не немцам).
Holos — "целостность" у греков.
Salu, sol — "целый" у тохар.
Salute — пожелание "здоровья" на латыни при встрече (отсюда слово "салют", в смысле "привет").

Что нам это говорит? Что скорее всего не просто "целовать" значит "приветствовать", а также "быть здоровым, целостным" и даже возможно в языческом смысле "святым".

А более того — вероятно, это общеиндоевропейская основа, раз она есть и в латыни и у германцев, и у славян. И что желали быть "целыми и невредимыми" так уже многие тысячелетия подряд, еще когда существовала индоевропейская культурно-языковая общность, в которой латинские, славянские и германские племена еще не успели разойтись (грубо оценивая, 4-5 тысячелетий назад).

И только потом слово "целовать" обросло в русском языке таким мощным вторичным смыслом, что изначальный смысл потерялся.

Так что, итальянское "salut" родственно словам "целую" и "hello".
А "целитель" родственно английскому "healer" и греческому "holos".
Звучат до сих пор похоже, только с небольшими диалектическими особенностями перехода первой буквы (там, где у германцев h, у славян часто бывает "ц" или "с").

Языки ближе, чем кажется.

Comment: А можно авторитетный источник, подтверждающий родственность, скажем, "целый" и "целовать"? Шут с ними, с германцами, но тут принято на вопрос отвечать аргументировано, а не проповеди читать.

Answer (score 0):

А также в народном языке встречается слово "почеломкаемся", то есть поцелуемся.

> Ну, я зла на тебя не питаю. Давай почеломкаемся, старик! ― И я ощутил прикосновение щеки Ликоспастова (Булгаков)

Comment: Ксения, ну кто начинает ответ с "а также"?!

Answer (score -1):

Поддержу ответ **Рафачки**

Тоже пришёл к выводу, что слово скорей всего происходит от слова **человать(ся)**

В [новгородских берестяных грамотах](http://gramoty.ru/dnd/full/710Ukazat.pdf) наряду с **`цѣлоую тѧ`** встречается **`чѣлоую т(ѧ)`** (№ 823), а также  **`чѣлɣю тѧ`** (№ 829).

В грамоте [№ 140](http://gramoty.ru/dnd/g10.pdf) фигурирует фраза **`марко целомо бьѥть ɣпомни цто`**, которую переводят как **"Марко челом бьёт, вспомни, что"**.
Как видим, слово **чело** в древнем Новгороде произносилось в том числе со звуком **Ц** - **`цело`**, как и многие другие слова, в которых в современном русском произносится (или пишется) **Ч**, например **что** - **`цто`**

Таким образом, с одной стороны, есть глагол **человать**, означающий очевидно **поцелуй**, и сформированный от корня **чело**, а с другой, есть существительное **цело**, как вариант произношения **чело**, что указывает на возможность такой же вариативности и между словами **целовать** и **человать**, кроме того, что в грамотах уже присутствуют оба варианта.

Cвязь со словом **целый** и якобы **пожеланием здоровья** выглядит неправдоподобной, во-первых потому, что в современном языке не прослеживается семантической связи между понятиями **здоровье** и **целос(тнос)ть**, кроме изолированных выражений "цел и невредим", "остаться целым" (и, как в комментариях подсказали, слова "целитель"), которые вместе с тем имеют отношение не столько к здоровью, сколько к отсутствию увечий (то есть все члены на месте), и не применяются для описания отсутствия болезней и общего здравия и благополучия, вне связи с попаданием в экстремальные ситуации, а во-вторых потому, что в языке всегда происходит перенос значений из физической, вещественной сферы в сферу абстрактных понятий и идей, и вероятность переноса значения такого условного действия, как пожелание здоровья, на физическую сферу, к которой принадлежит поцелуй, по-моему достаточно невелика.

Этимологические словари неубедительны.

Comment: Поддерживая ответ Рафачки, вопрос не забывайте: «Слова "целоваться" и "целое" — одного корня. Правда ли это?»

Comment: _...В современном языке не прослеживается семантической связи между понятиями здоровье и целос(тнос)ть_. Знаете такое слово **целитель**? И, кстати, это не только костоправ.

Comment: я считаю это ошибочной этимологией

Comment: действительно, я не учёл связь со здоровьем слова **целитель**, но **исцелять** и **целовать** довольно далеко отстоят друг от друга семантически, можно предположить, что **целитель** изначально лечил физические увечья, а не болезни, а позже в это понятие было включено лечение и  заболеваний

Comment: тем, кто возражает против предложенной этимологии, стоит попытаться объяснить отношение древненовгородского слова **человать** к слову **целый**... кроме того, мне знакомо фонетическое явление замены звука **Ч** на звук **Ц** в диалектах, но известно ли в языке обратное явление? даже если этимология от слова **человать** с корнем **чело** недоказуема, она имеет ровно столько же шансов, что и этимологияи от слова "цел"